# Is there a relationship between submatrices of A and submatrices of A^{-1}

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a matrix $A$ of order $d$, and its inverse $A^{-1}$. I am trying to find out whether there is some kind of relationship between submatrices of the two. Is there any relationship regarding the invertibility of submatrices of $A$ and $A^{-1}$? Maybe something about the rank of such submatrices.

For example, how true is the following statement: if there is a submatrix of order $c$ of $A$ that has full rank then there is a submatrix of of $A^{-1}$ of order $d-c$ that is also full rank.

Comment: If $A $ is a matrix of full rank $d $, it has submatrices of all smaller ranks.

Comment: That is known, but what about submatrices of $A$ and $A^{-1}$?

Comment: But $A^{-1}$ only exists if $A$ is full rank (and if so, its inverse is also full rank).

Comment: Your "for example" question doesn't seem to involve $A^{-1}$ (so, how is it an example?).

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, N A?

Comment: Are you still here, N A?

Comment: Thanks! I see your poof and it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answers the question: if a $d\times d$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then it has $c\times c$ submatrices of full rank for every $c$, $1\le c\le d$.

The proof is quite simple. By using expansion along a row or column, repeatedly if necessary, the determinant of $A$ can be expressed as linear combination of determinants of $c\times c$ matrices. If there were a value of $c$ for which no $c\times c$ submatrix had full rank, then all those submatrices would have determinant zero, and then $A$ would have determinant zero, contradicting its invertibility.

Comment: And likewise the same is true of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, yes – $A^{-1}$ is invertible, after all.